# Remove Multiple Files in one Line PS

Tags: windows, powershell, delete-file

I was wondering if there is a elegant way to remove multiple files in a dictonary if they exist, with PowerShell.

My current attempt is not quite working.

```
$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6,$var7,$var8,$var9,$var10,$var11,$var12,$var13 |
    ?{Test-Path "\\C:\Windows\system32\$_"} |
    %{del "\\C:\Windows\system32\$_" -Force}
```

Has somebody a good idea?

Comment: Get-ChildItem with your specific filter piped into Remove-Item should do the job.

Comment: You should describe what is not working. Do you get an error message?

Comment: What are the values of your variables? How are the variables populated? And why are you using a list of individual variables instead of an array in the first place?

Comment: Remove-Item -Path $var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6,$var7,$var8,$var9,$var10,$var11,$var12,$var13 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You for your help,
I used variables, because i needed to remove a large amount of this files in different *folders/keys/keyvalues*. But not all the time (*never*) in the same constellation. But as suggested, i could have used a string instead.

I used this code to remove the files, and supresse error messages. For example, if the file has been already deleted.

```
?{$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6,$var7,$var8,$var9,$var10,$var11,$var12,$var13 | ForEach-Object{ Remove-Item -Path C:\Windows\system32\$_}}
```

Afterwards i check if there was a problem, and the files still exist. In that case, they need to be removed manually.

```
$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5,$var6,$var7,$var8,$var9,$var10,$var11,$var12,$var13 | ForEach-Object{ IF((Test-Path C:\Windows\system32\$_ -PathType Leaf) -eq $True) {echo "C:\Windows\system32\$_ could not be deleted" }}
```

Greetings